# Setup and analysis of deterministic simulation (Design of experiments, ANOVA)

Tags: anova, python, simulation, fractional-factorial

My problem is as follows:

I have a time series simulation (implemented in Python), which is roughly about an abstract modeled storage object digesting and creating energy flows. These (resulting) energy flows are eventually causing revenues. In total, the simulation runs over a predefined time horizon and its output is e.g. profitability index on the storage investment.

Now of course the simulation outcome depends on how (all) the input parameters are set. However, if parameters are set at the same values, each arbitrarily number of reproductions of the simulation will yield the same outcome.

Let's say, there is in total about 30 parameters (IVs), from which I assume 25 to be set at a "fixed" value. For the remaining 5, I want to do a sensitivity analysis (relative importance of the parameters) on the outcome (DV). The IVs are categorical as well as quantitative data, the DV is quantitative. Ideally, for each of the 5 parameters, 3 different values (i.e., levels) shall be investigated. This leads me to a setup following the Design of Experiments approach, with e.g. a $3^5$ full factorial design (i.e., resulting in $243$ simulations to-be-run).

Eventually, I want to be able to say something like "regardless of how I vary the other parameters, parameter X has an average impact of Z% on the outcome" (am I right thinking of "magnitude of effects" here?). As a side effect, it would of course be interesting to measure interaction effects between the parameters.

Can you tell me whether DoE approach serves my purpose and which method may be best suited to answer my question (e.g. multi-factor ANOVA)? I read quite a lot of literature but am still not sure which approach is most suitable for this kind of simulation model.